# how to translate using gettext on xampp server on OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6

Tags: php, translation, gettext

I am working on a website that is using gettext for translation. The website is translating properly on servers of other machines but not on mine (OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6).
I have follow the following tutorial to install gettext on mac:

[link](https://topicdesk.com/downloads/tutorials/installing-gettext-on-os-x-10-11-x-el-capitan/) to the tutorial I followed

After the installation, gettext is not still working. 
Can someone help me here??

Comment: what errors did you get? Did you check the logs?

Comment: there is no error in the console. the page is not just translated when I try to translate it.

Answer (score 1):

I followed pretty much the same instructions on Sierra (maybe you have messed up at some point?):

1. Install the latest version of Xcode Command Line Tools. (by entering the following command in the terminal: `xcode-select –install`)
2. Download the latest version of [gettext](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/) and extract it to /Source or whatever you like.
3. In the /Source director enter in the terminal: `./Configure`, `make`, and `sudo make install`
4. [Download](http://php.net/releases/) the PHP version that matches your system and extract it
5. Change in the PHP source to the directory ext/gettext and enter the following commands: `phpize`, `./Configure`, `make`, and `sudo make install` (each on a separate line).
   At this point you might get an SIP error, because the install has no access to /usr/libexec/php/extensions. However, the extension was created in the PHP source folder ext/gettext/modules
6. Create a local extension folder: `mkdir -p /usr/local/macoperator/lib/php/extensions` and copy the newly created gettext.so extension to this folder
7. Reference the local extension folder in your /etc/php.ini. Just add the following line at the end:

   ```
   extension_dir = "/usr/local/macoperator/lib/php/extensions"
   [gettext]
   extension=gettext.so
   ```
8. Finally, make sure apache is restarted, by issuing: `server-apachectl graceful`
9. Checking `phpinfo()`, do you see:

   GetText Support              enabled

Alternatively, you could try install PHP via [Homebrew](http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/).